Run a shell script which terminates the go application
I need to restart a go application process on debian, this requires running the following bash file:
systemctl stop go_service && other_command && systemctl start go_service

I try to use the following code:
cmd := exec.Command("bash", scriptPath)
// Start the command asynchronously
if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
    eError("Error starting command: %v\n", err)
    return
}

but the first bash command terminates the process and it never completes the next commands which should start it again
any idea how to run the whole bash file ?

Are you saying that the service itself is trying to run a script that restarts that same service? Because in general, I'd avoid doing that at all. Can you tell us more about other_command? If it's doing something like cleanup, make it an ExecStopPost for the service; if it's doing setup, make it an ExecStartPre; if it's only conditionally needed, have an ExecStartPre that checks whether it needs it and runs it, etc (keeping a flag on disk for "do we need to do this operation before starting back up?" is straightforward enough).

That way all you have to do is make your process exit; as long as systemd is configured to restart the service after such exits, it'll make everything else happen on its own.

There are other options -- you can change how systemd is configured to manage shutdown to tell it to shut down only the MainPID and not the whole process group, for example -- but those other options tend to have undesirable side effects and I can't recommend them without a lot more details explaining why anything that's more in line with good practices is outside consideration.

echo task.sh | at now can be used to execute commands in an external way, but there's something wrong with the initial approach, so as it said above better to consider other options

@yvs2014, systemd-run provides a modern alternative that works for anyone with systemd already active (as we know the OP has) without relying on atd.

If what you are saying is true, "the first bash command terminates the process and it never completes the next commands which should start it again" then that would imply that the "systemctl stop go_service" command is returning a non-zero status. Is there any output from the "systemctl stop go_service" command?

@Cloudlady Here is the thing: The process calling the bash instance which is supposed to interpret the. && ... will be terminated - and so will be ALL it's child processes, including said bash instance.

@CharlesDuffy Running the bash file from the terminal does everything fine, the service is stopped, update file extracted and the service file is overwritten, then it's started again
the problem is doing this from the go app itself, I want the go app to trigger the bash script so that the user can click "update & restart", is this possible ? ChatGPT is hallucinating.
I prefer not to use systemd and keep the whole setup limited to the go app and a bash script "if possible"

I really advise against that; we're no longer in the Bad Old Days of self-daemonizing software (with each program having its own unique mechanism for trying to restart after failures/reboot/etc, its own mechanism for trying to manage locking / mutexes / control, its own mechanism for waiting for dependencies to be available, &c) for a reason. Again, it's not that it absolutely can't be done, but if you don't have enough background to answer this question yourself -- familiarity with cgroups, process accounting, &c &c -- you're probably not in a good place to weigh the tradeoffs.

(I'm not a fan of systemd particularly -- if you ask me to build an embedded system from scratch I'm more likely to use runit or s6 for process supervision -- but I'm much more not a fan of the wild west where every piece of software builds a completely bespoke mechanism for managing itself, and half of them do it very badly or outright ignore major parts of the problem space)

...at least with everyone using systemd there's a completely uniform way to be notified or run an arbitrary hook when any software changes state, a uniform way to indicate which components should be started at boot, a unified way to view per-process logs, a unified way to give a process a private copy of tmpfs or lock it off from inspecting/changing home directory contents or sandbox which syscalls it can invoke or configure something else to be started only after it's finished initializing; &c, &c. &c. Pick a competitor and those too will have unified ways to do most of things.

(...mind, I'd also argue that you should never give a service enough permissions to update its own executable -- that means that a user who subverts that service is necessarily capable of persisting the damage they've done to run code of their choice on reboot/restart/similar; better to keep updaters out-of-band, run under a separate account with more permissions than the service itself; even better than that to go with a Nix-esque mechanism where "updates" consist of adding new executables, not overwriting old ones in place, with signatures and hashes available to verify integrity).

Again, everything you're asking for is possible. I'm just advising (as a grumpy greybeard who's spent time as the dev lead for self-updating security products) that a lot of it is unwise. (What I'd argue is an ideal architecture -- and one I've actually used in real-world products -- is one where you've got a dm_verity-esque read-only, signed root filesystem, and an "upgrade" consists of rebooting into a new kernel using a new root fs; make your firmware check the signature over the kernel and you get a chain of trust going all the way back).

@CharlesDuffy I'm not that experienced with linux like you, but I like your idea about a new executable for every update, however, the golang app is restarted through a systemd service file, which has the path to the go executable, so with every update a new service file should be created ? or how can you solve that ?
I'm doing this whole thing for simplifying the update process, the update would be downloaded and the app restarted automatically, without even having to login to the terminal, just a click on a web interface

@MarkusWMahlberg, exactly, do you have recommendations based on my scenario ?
is it possible to start the bash as a new process so that it may continue even if the calling process is terminated ?
Thank you!

Your systemd service file can invoke a shim that's responsible for finding the latest correctly-signed downloaded file and then execing it. (Important to use exec so the process your script replaces itself with takes on the script's own PID, so the MainPID that systemd assigned is inherited by the real process when the shim hands over control).

(if you want to write the shim itself in Go, you'll want to use https://codeberg.org/msantos/execve; the built in os/exec module always forks off a subprocess before the exec, vs replacing the existing process in-place as done by an exec with no preceding fork)

...well, I say that. https://pkg.go.dev/syscall#Exec is wrapping an older interface, but in a fair set of cases it's good enough. (Passing paths around and not pre-resolved file descriptors makes it a little harder to protect against some classes of vulnerabilities -- like TOCTOU attacks that change a symlink to point to a different target between signature-checking time and execution time -- but as long as you're thinking about those attacks and have other ways to mitigate them...)

To reiterate: The shim should just be verifying signatures on content then starting the newest correctly-signed executable (and think about a one-way ratchet to prevent downgrades so that after you fix a security bug an attacker can't reintroduce it with an older correctly-signed executable). You don't want to make it responsible for downloading those executables, because that requires giving the service enough permissions to rewrite its own files -- put that on the other end of a privilege boundary, performed by a program that's as small, simple, and well-audited as possible.

I solved this by using:
systemctl restart go_service
